# Trouble adding/putting a text file with Xcode 

Tags: xcode

I'm having trouble adding a text file with Xcode. I have the coding setup to read it but I don't know where to put the .txt file. I had the .txt under the Product folder but it would give me an undesired output. I searched with google and asked my instructor but he has no idea. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What undesired output you are getting?

drag and drop your text file on xcode 
then

```
NSString *textFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"textfilename" ofType: @"txt"];
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath
                  usedEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding
                         error:nil];
```

Comment: I wrote this code out:                                               if (!stockDataIn)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open input file. Program terminates." << endl;
        exit (1);
    }                                                                                    only if it fails.. and it fails all the time.

Comment: I'm not worried about the coding since the professor verified it. I'm only concerned as to where the text file should be put so the compiler could read it.